# trouble installing rmagick gem on mac 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I have tried all of the SO and solutions I found on git, but no luck. I am trying to run bundle install on an existing project on a new mbp retina w/ mavericks. Below is my trace:

```
Installing rmagick (2.13.2)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

brew doctor output

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /usr/local/bin/gpg-error-config
    /usr/local/bin/ksba-config
    /usr/local/bin/pkg-config

Warning: Your Homebrew is not installed to /usr/local
You can install Homebrew anywhere you want, but some brews may only build
correctly if you install in /usr/local. Sorry!

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /usr/local/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

Comment: Are you using Homebrew for package management?  If not, what are you using?

Comment: Yes I am, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: You may want to look here - http://superuser.com/questions/361435/i-have-compiled-imagemagick-on-my-centos-and-rmagick-wont-install .  While that answer is about CentOS, the key question is where is the MagickCore.pc file.  Check 'ls /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc' and, if that's not present, do a 'find / -name MagickCore.pc' to get the path.

Comment: yeah, I have seen that post. This is where my MagickCore.pc file lives /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-0/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc - I am unclear on what the sumlinks should look like now

Comment: Can you run 'brew doctor' and see if your imagemagick links are correct?  It seems like you're missing a symlink.  On my system I have  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc -> ../../Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-0/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc

Comment: the output from brew doctor is above. Some how I screwed that up.

Comment: So this is probably the issue - "Warning: Your Homebrew is not installed to /usr/local".  That's really not a good idea - if this is a new machine I'd go back and reinstall Homebrew in /usr/local.

Comment: that is actually the path that I was on for the last hour. Do you recomend I uninstall the previous home-brew install first? That is apparently not trivial either

Comment: That's probably what I'd do.  Have you seen this gist - https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223 ?

Comment: well, unfortunately I have the same problem after a proper install of home-brew. When I run brew doctor I get the ready to brew message . But I still get the error above after I brew install imagemagick the bundle install

Comment: Ok.  Go back through it.  What does brew doctor say now?  Where is the MagickCore.pc file?

Comment: Brew doctor says "Your system is ready to brew." and MagickCore.pc is here /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40481/discussion-between-peter-goldstein-and-isea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@isea and I went through this in chat.  Key issues were:

1. Homebrew was installed in a non-standard location.  As a general rule, that's dangerous.
2. Once Homebrew was uninstalled and reinstalled, the pkg-config package needed to be installed using 'brew install pkg-config'

This fixed the issue.

Comment: This is the simplest and most straightforward explanation I have seen for this issue and your advice worked like a charm.  Thank you!